# Cannot Connect to Cloud SQL from App Engine Standard using a VPC Static Ip Address with Egress Setting: all-traffic

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-vpc

We have two separate projects, project A: has a Cloud SQL instance (has both public IP and private IP)

Now we have a new project B: It's a App Engine standard Java11 environment. For this project we have a requirement where we need to make a REST API call to a third party api, and it has to come from a specific GEO location. So we have setup on provisioning a static IP address explicitly in the geography where our app engine service is provisioned. We followed this documentation: [Set up a static outbound IP address](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/outbound-ip-addresses#static-ip)

When we deploy the App Engine after those changes, it is unable to reach the CLoudSQL anymore from project A, however when we remove from **app.yaml** the `egress_setting: all-traffic` and re-deploy, it connects to the Cloud Sql successfully but then we are unable to call our REST Api call, as third party api returns back 403 because of our IP address location.

Note that both Project A and Project B are in the same region.

Our app.yaml file looks like this:
`

```
runtime: java11
instance_class: F2
env_variables:
  GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB : ''
vpc_access_connector:
  name: projects/<projectB-id>/locations/northamerica-northeast1/connectors/cb-connector
  egress_setting: all-traffic
```

This is the connection url used for Cloud SQL (MySql),
We have tried with the cloud SQL private IP as follow

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://<cloudSql-PrivateIp>:3306/_operations?user=<user>&password=<pass>&ipTypes=PRIVATE
```

Then we have also tried with cloud SQL public IP as follow:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://_operations?cloudSqlInstance=<projectA-id>northamerica-northeast1:<sql-instanceName>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=<user>&password=<pass>
```

We have followed these instructions here to connect from App-Engine to CloudSql: [Connect from App Engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#java) We tried with both option Public Ip and Private IP, but we kept on getting a Communication Link error. It seems to timeout after a while loading. That is when the `egress_setting: all-traffic` is set in **app.yaml**. If we remove that `egress_setting: all-traffic`, then connection works perfectly but we are unable to make our REST call to that third party api we need.

Not sure how we can set this up so we can still have connection to both the cloud Sql instance (project A) and still be able to reach our third party api from App engine (project B) using a static outbound IP. If someone can share some insight on what possible cause or solution that we can do?

**EDIT**
We have also tried to make a peering vpc between project A and project B, but still not working when `egress_setting: all-traffic` is set in *app.yaml* file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the issue was with the IP range that was configured in my VPC. The static egress IP range did not include the IP address of my Cloud SQL instance. After adding the appropriate IP range, now everything is working.